# Sending an image to an API, but receiving an "API RESPONSE: Receipt upload failed" response. Why?

Tags: php, curl, php-curl, image-upload

I am sending the data (base64 string of image file) from the postman to the API, it will take base 64 string & covert to file. And this file send to an another external API and gets the response from there. Entire code it is written down here:

- Decode the Base64 string to obtain the raw image data.
- Save the decoded image data to a temporary file.
- Include the file path or name in the JSON payload.
- Send the JSON payload in a cURL request.

[image]

```php
<?php 
//takes the data from postman post request
$postfp = fopen("php://input", "r");
$postData = "";
while($data = fread($postfp, 1024)){
$postData .= $data;
}

//it will decode the json data
$data = json_decode($postData);

$base64String = $data->{'content'};

// Decode the Base64 string 
$imageData = base64_decode($base64String); 

// Create a unique file name for the image 
$imageFileName = 'image_'  .  uniqid()  .  '.jpg'; 

// Get the system's temporary directory 
$tempDir = sys_get_temp_dir(); 

// Path to store the image in the temporary directory 
$imagePath = $tempDir  .  '/'  .  $imageFileName; 

// Write the binary data to the image 
file file_put_contents($imagePath, $imageData); 

$exp_id = 90;

// JSON data to send in the request 
$post_data = [ 'image' => $imagePath]; 

$protocol = 'https';
$domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$request_url = "/rfnextgenapi/api/v1/expense-category". $exp_id;

$url = "${protocol}://${domain}". $request_url ;

// Authentication credentials 
$username = 'your_username'; $password = 'your_password'; 

// Initialize cURL session $
ch = curl_init(); 

// Set cURL options 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($post_data)); // JSON data curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // Set HTTP authentication method and credentials 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password"); 

// Set the Content-Type header to indicate JSON data 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [ 'Content-Type: application/json', ]); // Execute the cURL request 

$response = curl_exec($ch); // Check for cURL errors 

if (curl_errno($ch)) 
{ 
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch); 
} 

// Close cURL session curl_close($ch); 

// Delete the temporary image file 
unlink($imagePath); 

// Display API response 
echo $response; ?>
```

**API response:**

> "Receipt upload failed"

Comment: There are syntax errors in the code in your question. Can you please test whether your code runs before asking a question about it?

Comment: no syntax error, it working. You can see api request & response in the uploaded screenshot

Comment: You removed one syntax error when you edited your code, there are two left. When I correct those I get a lot of warnings, those are due to `$data` not being defined. Clearly this is not the code you're actually running.

Comment: it is part of code I uploaded,

Comment: There are still 2 syntax erros in your code. Never mind. You're _not_ sending the image file to the other API, you're only sending the path, on your own server, to the API. Is that what you intend to do, or do you actually want to send the image itself, like you seem to imply? Also: Instead of reading the input in chunks you can do `$postData = file_get_contents('php://input');`.